# php resolve bash alias pointing to script

Tags: php, bash

I am interested in having a bunch of aliases setup that point to a particular script. An example would be:

```
alias foo='php test.php'
alias bar='php test.php'
```

in `test.php`, I want to be able to access `$args[0]` and have it read `foo` and `bar` respectively. Currently as it stands, `$args[0]` would be `test.php`.

Is there a way around this in PHP 5.5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a php issue. That's a shell issue. The alias is handled by the shell. php doesn't even know it existed.

You would need to use symlinks `foo -> test.php` and `bar -> test.php` for this to work I believe.

If you just want to use the alias name as a first argument to the php script you could also use a function instead:

```
foo() {
    php test.php foo "$@"
}

bar() {
    php test.php bar "$@"
}
```